# How to implement per-bundle 404 page in symfony 2.x

Tags: symfony

In one of the projects I'm working a custom 404 page needs to be implemented for each bundle.

Inside the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) there is nothing mentioned for such functionality.

I was discussing the issue with some colleagues and was told that it has to use the kernel.exception event, alas this one lacks the information which bundle is calling it.

IMHO this should be fixed by applying a patch to symfony router component which would allow the developer to specify catch-all route which could handle the case further.

Another option would be to change the behavior of the RouterInterface::match method to return consistent output containing the matched path and the bundle which matched it. Currently this is not possible, because it throws an exception if match fails and does not give you any information at all, while it could.

For example, I have an ApiBundle which is defined to handle urls starting with "/api". Currently the only way to handle this one and set custom 404 page is to get the request at the time of the kernel.exception and preg_match() the url. This, however, is hardcoding that should be avoided as the bundle should not have such knowledge - it is defined under the app/config/routing file.

What's your opinion?
I would appreciate any other workarounds as well.

Comment: How about overriding the template in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception` with a blank twig file and then extending from it inside your bundles?

Comment: What's the point? app/Resources file is meant to override everything after the bundles have been applied. Even if I extend the file from within my bundles, it won't get loaded at all.

Comment: Your goal is to implement a custom 404 page for each bundle right? If you put a block like `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` in the file `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig` and then in every bundle you create a twig file extending from it and writting in this block. I haven't tested but it would make sense to me to do it this way.

Comment: I guess I was wrong. I found [this link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4382) and [this one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1511) saying there is no simple way to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up implementing my custom [ExceptionController](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/twig.html#config-twig-exception-controller) which dispatches an event I called 'ourCompany.exception_response'.

- The default bundle has a listener set with priority -1024.
- If custom bundle processes the exception and sets its response, the event has to be marked and the propagation to be stopped.
- The custom bundle can use the service container to get whatever it wants in order to determine whether to process the exception or no.